# Eclipse crashes when opening the Run menu (trying to run)

Tags: eclipse, multithreading

i'm using RHEL linux to run Helios Eclipse 3.6, and just recently, whenever i try to right click on a project and mouse over to "Run As", eclipse freezes itself and the whole OS. Mousing over to anywhere else is fine, like 'close project' or 'build configurations'... Basically, eclipse works fine for everything except running a project. If i do CTRL+F11, it also freezes because it's trying to open the "Run As" screen.

here's what i have in my eclipse.ini file:

```
-startup
  plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.1.R36x_v20101122_1400.jar
  --launcher.library
  plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_1.1.2.R36x_v20101019_1345
  -product
  org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
  --launcher.defaultAction
  openFile
  -showsplash
  org.eclipse.platform
  --launcher.XXMaxPermSize
  256m
  --launcher.defaultAction
  openFile
  -vmargs
  -Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.XULRunnerPath=''
  -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
  -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
  -Xms128m
  -Xmx512m
```

The only things that i recall having changed recently was setting the stack size to be higher, -Xss500m or something... but i remember taking out that line before i consistently see these eclipse freeze. (not sure if this is relevant, but one time, also recently, i set asize something ridiculous like 9 terabytes of data in a thread that i ran off of an android project on eclipse. later i get the eclipse freeze and i had to do a manual force shutdown).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try a new Eclipse workspace (File / Switch Workspace).  If that works, there is maybe a very large cache or something stored within the old workspace metadata.  How large is your `.metadata` directory?  If more than 1 GB, for example, look for any excessively large directories, and any cache files that can at least be temporarily moved elsewhere to see if that improves things.

I'd also try the usual of upgrading to the latest version of Eclipse, as well as the JDK you're using to run it with.

Comment: i made a new workspace and that seemed to be working so far... i hope it stays this way, because the other workspace used to work... 

i deleted the log files under .metadata since one was like 1M and there was a backup log of 1M. it probably had something to do with the proprietary plugins that im working with. Thanks so much for the answer, you saved me the hassle of having to fix this on Christmas day :D